# Python OOP - Operating objects method's output

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to use a method inside an object to operate it, but it keeps me telling that the type of the data didn't match.

I'm still learning and I know that this kind of problem must be something that everyone encounters sooner or later in his learning process, but I couldn't find a clear explanation neither a question like this one here (it can be my needToImproveSearchingSkills)

```
def runSimulation(num_robots, speed, width, height, min_coverage, num_trials, robot_type):
    """
    Runs NUM_TRIALS trials of the simulation and returns the mean number of
    time-steps needed to clean the fraction MIN_COVERAGE of the room.

    The simulation is run with NUM_ROBOTS robots of type ROBOT_TYPE, each with
    speed SPEED, in a room of dimensions WIDTH x HEIGHT.

    num_robots: an int (num_robots > 0)
    speed: a float (speed > 0)
    width: an int (width > 0)
    height: an int (height > 0)
    min_coverage: a float (0 <= min_coverage <= 1.0)
    num_trials: an int (num_trials > 0)
    robot_type: class of robot to be instantiated (e.g. StandardRobot or
                RandomWalkRobot)
    """
    space = RectangularRoom(width, height)
    bots = []
    times = []
    total = 0

    for n in range(num_robots):
        bots.append(StandardRobot(space, speed)) #needs change to robot_type

    for s in range(num_trials):
        test_time = 0
        while space.getNumCleanedTiles/(width*height) < min_coverage:
            for bot in bots:
                bot.updatePositionAndClean()
            test_time += 1
        times.append(test_time)

    for time in times:
        total += time
    return total / len(times)
```

When I try to run it, it tells me that `space.getNumCleanedTiles/(width*height) < min_coverage` cannot be calculated. Throwing at me a TypeError `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instancemethod' and 'int'`

I didn't include the rest of the code, because it isn't important and it's clear what call does what.

Comment: You are iterating over an emtpy list it seems.

Comment: You're right, i just forgot an s in there.
Fixed now.

Comment: what type `space.getNumCleanedTiles` returns?

Comment: You forgot to call your instance method. Put `()` after `getNumCleanedTiles`.

Comment: It's `return len(self.cleaned)`.

I'll try to check the type now.

Comment: @luther got it. I can't believe how I missed it.
Thanks. I thought it may be something I didn't learn yet about methods and/or types.

Answer (score 0):

@luther got the answer, I forgot to put `()` after `getNumCleanedTiles`